# Setting a data filter to a string field containing a number > than a variable containing a number

Tags: database, delphi

I'm using Delphi 10.2.
I'm trying to filter a ClientDataSet to generate a report of only new records. 'Idnm' is a string field containing a number.

The following code fails because **Idnm** is left justified and six digit numbers starting with 6 show up as being greater than '5123456'.

```
Var StartID : string;
... 
StartID := '5123456';
ClientDataSet1.Filter := 'Idnm > ' + StartID; 
ClientDataSet1.Filtered := true;
```

How can I format **Idnm** or **StartID** so that the filter works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, using the Filter property of a TClientDataSet filter to do comparisons between integer values does not work properly because the underlying expression-processing does not readily support type-conversion from string representations to integer values.  It is much more straightforward to leave the Filter property blank and use the `OnFilterRecord` event to determine whether records match your integer filter criterion.  Something like this:

```
var
  iStartID : Integer;  //  a field of your form or datamodule

[...]

  StartID := 5123456;
  iStartID := StrToInt(StartID);

procedure TForm1.CDS1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
// set Accept to True if the current record matches the filter condition(s)
begin
  //  Set iStartID from your StartID value before activating the filter
  //  CDS1ID is a persistent field defined for the ID.  Otherwise, use
  //  CDS1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger
  Accept := CDS1ID.AsInteger > iStartID;
end;
```

When you want to change the StartID, toggle CDS1.Filtered off (False), change the StartID/iStartID values and then turn Filtered back on (True).

Note, I've used the iStartID variable to avoid the performance overhead of doing CDS.FieldByName for each row in the dataset.

Comment: OnFilterRecord worked.   You have an error in the code.  StartID is a string so the codr should read:  StartID := '5123456';  iStartID := StrToInt(StartID);